# Query about summation in derivation of complex fourier series

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, summation, fourier-series

I was trying to follow a derivation on the complex fourier series, but I am a bit confused at one particular step. In the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ft5iyapkSqM, at 6:30, the proffessor tries to merge the sums together. I am confused as to how he does this.

From 6:30, we have that $f(\alpha) = a_0 + \sum _{1} ^{\infty}\frac{a_n-ib_n}{2}e^{in\alpha}+\sum _{-\infty} ^{-1}\frac{a_{-n}+ib_{-n}}{2}e^{in\alpha}$. He then labels the expression $\frac{a_n-ib_n}{2}$ as $c_n$ and $a_0 $ as $c_0$. This labelling reduces the above summation to the following: $f(\alpha) = \sum _{0} ^{\infty}c_n e^{in\alpha}+\sum _{-\infty} ^{-1}\frac{a_{-n}+ib_{-n}}{2}e^{in\alpha}$. I do not see how he manages to equate the expression $\frac{a_{-n}+ib_{-n}}{2}$ as $c_{n}$ for negative n, since this expression is the conjugate of $c_n$ for negative n. Can someone explain how the summation was reduced from the first expression to the known: $f(\alpha) = \sum _{-\infty} ^{\infty}c_ne^{in\alpha}$.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what the question is. It may be helpful to note that no, $a-ib$ is *not* the conjugate of  $a+ib$ unless $a$ and $b$ are real. Now, if $f$ is real-valued then $a_n$ and $b_n$ *are*  real. So the above appears to show that $c_{-n}=\overline{c_n}$. This is no problem, since the $c_n$ *do* satisfy that (if $f$ is real-valued).

Comment: The question is how the summation was reduced from what he has in the video at 6:30 to the final complex fourier series.

Comment: @VishalJain I can't figure out what aspect of that "reduction" you don't get. We know for example that $\sin(nt)=(e^{int}-e^{-int})/(2i)$, so $\sum a_n\sin(nt)=\sum a_n (e^{int}-e^{-int})/(2i)$ and similarly for $\sum b_n\cos(nt)$. Now collect terms that have an $e^{int}$ in them...

Comment: Being more specific its the fact that he has reduced the summation by saying that $c_n = \frac{a_n - i b_n}{2} $ and that $c_n$ for negative $n$ equals $\frac{a_b + i b_n}{2} $. I dont see how for negative n, we know the $b_n$ term's sign changes.

Comment: Like I said, you simply collect terms: $a\cos(t)+b\sin(t)=a(e^{it}+e^{-it})/2+b(e^{it}-e^{-it})/(2i)=\frac{a-ib}2e^{it}+\frac{a+ib}2e^{-it}$.